# org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: Data provider mismatch

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a xls file with 2 columns of test data. For each column I want to have a test method.

Now I know how to use dataprovider to read the xls file and provide the test data to a test method. But how can I use the same dataprovider for multiple tests?

I have below code and once i run this code getting error
my Code is:

```
@Test(dataProvider="TestData")
public void test1(String Username ) throws InterruptedException
{           
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"UserName\"]")).sendKeys(Username);               
}

@Test(dataProvider="TestData")
public void test2(String Password)
{   
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Password\"]")).sendKeys(Password);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"columns\"]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/input")).click();
}




@DataProvider (name="TestData")
public  Object [][] readexcel(Method method) throws BiffException, IOException 
        {

File f=new File("E:\\Selenium\\Eclips\\NCPDP\\src\\TestData\\TestData.xls");
            Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(f);
            Sheet s = w.getSheet("TestData");
            int rows = s.getRows();
            int columns =s.getColumns();

            String inputData[][]=new String[rows-1][columns];
            try {
                for(int i=1;i<rows;i++)
                    {
                    for(int j=0;j<columns;j++)
                        {
            Cell c=s.getCell(j,i);
            inputData[i-1][j]=c.getContents();

                        }

                    }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }

        return inputData;
        }
```

Output:

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2 Starting ChromeDriver
>   2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387) on port 47795 Only local connections are allowed. Feb 12, 2019 1:15:28 PM
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
>   Detected dialect: OSS FAILED: test1
>   org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException:  Data provider
>   mismatch Method: test1([Parameter{index=0, type=java.lang.String,
>   declaredAnnotations=[]}]) Arguments: [(java.lang.String)
>   TESTQA41,(java.lang.String) Ncpdp@1234]   at
>   org.testng.internal.reflect.DataProviderMethodMatcher.getConformingArguments(DataProviderMethodMatcher.java:45)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Parameters.injectParameters(Parameters.java:796)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:982)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>
> FAILED: test2 org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: 
>   Data provider mismatch Method: test2([Parameter{index=0,
>   type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}]) Arguments:
>   [(java.lang.String) TESTQA41,(java.lang.String) Ncpdp@1234]   at
>   org.testng.internal.reflect.DataProviderMethodMatcher.getConformingArguments(DataProviderMethodMatcher.java:45)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Parameters.injectParameters(Parameters.java:796)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:982)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>
> ===============================================
>       Default test
>
> ## Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Skips: 0
>
> ## =============================================== Default suite Total tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Skips: 0

Comment: Please share full exception with Parameter details

Comment: Hello Ishita, Thanks for your reply, please check i have edited the post with full excption details

Answer (score 1):

If your `DataProvider` is returning two parameter you need to pass those two parameters to your `@Test` annotation.

**Your solution**

```
@Test(dataProvider="TestData")
public void test1(String Username,String Password) throws Exception
{           
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"UserName\"]")).sendKeys(Username);          
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Password\"]")).sendKeys(Password);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"columns\"]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/input")).click();
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but my concern is i want to use separate Test annotation for every column available in xls file. can we use multiple Test annotation for single data provider. if yes, then how we can implement in my code?

Comment: @satishtrimukhe You might be in wrong direction of using DataProvider scope, Excel Reader and many more. What you want to suppose to do is not correct way,

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/parameterization-using-xml-and-dataproviders-selenium.html
https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-parameters-data-provider/